# Hover transition doesn't work

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, transition

So I have been working on a project recently and the transition that I apply to a div doesn't work. Got no idea why!

Here is the CSS code

```
.stats .box {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255,0.07);
    color: white;
    padding: 40px 0;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 0.7s all ease-out;
    margin: 20px 0;

}

.stats h2 {
    margin: 25px 0 10px 0;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 200;
}

.stats h4 {
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.stats .box:hover {
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(102deg, #1ad2fd 11%, #008aff 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(102deg, #1ad2fd 11%, #008aff 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(102deg, #1ad2fd 11%, #008aff 100%);
    transition: 0.7s all ease-out;
}
```

Here is the HTML Code

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
<div class="box">
    <h2>4326</h2>
    <h4>Lines of Code</h4>
</div>
```

Here is the CodePen for it too if you wanna see it live http://codepen.io/PlatoCode/pen/qadvZV

Thank

Answer (score 0):

Transition does not support gradient animation the only thing you can do is work with opacity

```css
.box {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.07);
  color: black;
  padding: 40px 0;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.7s all ease-out;
  margin: 20px 0;
  position: relative;
}
h2 {
  margin: 25px 0 10px 0;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 200;
  z-index: 2;
}
h4 {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 15px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.box:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: 0.7s all ease-out;
  opacity: 0;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(102deg, #1ad2fd 11%, #008aff 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(102deg, #1ad2fd 11%, #008aff 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(102deg, #1ad2fd 11%, #008aff 100%);
  z-index: -1;
}
.box:hover:after {
opacity: 1;
  }
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="box">
    <h2>4326</h2>
    <h4>Lines of Code</h4>
  </div>
```

Comment: but if I set the opacity of .box to 0 then it won't show

Comment: if you want the content of the box to show you can move the gradient to a pseudo element like after and do it there

Comment: Great thanks! it works now, but I still can't set a background-color for the div that contains these elements. Here is the codepen for it http://codepen.io/PlatoCode/pen/qadvZV?editors=1100

Comment: Seems like your dark background prevents the gradient from showing up because it is z-index:-1 but you need that else the text gets overlaped. You probably have to split this in two containers one for the gradient and one for the text and then overlay the text container over the gradient.